# VS setup project prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio, setup-deployment

I've created a setup project for my app and I need to include some prerequisites.
How can I specify an order of prerequisites in which those are installed on a client machine?

Comment: I have created bootstrap manifest that contains Windows Installer 3.1  and .NET 3.5 standalone package.  All seems fine except that after Windows Installer is installed system reboot is required and after reboot installation doesn't proceed.  That is you have to run setup again which will try to install Windows Installer er (again) but this time won't ask for reboot.  How can my install package pick up from the point it left?